# Devolver un objeto de tipo especifico en Java

Tags: java, poo, objeto

El código que estoy implementando es un sistema de búsqueda y consulta de bicicletas, requiere implementar un método que recibe como argumento un String Id y devuelve un objeto de tipo Bicicleta, la función debe buscar en un arreglo de **Bicicletas** de la instancia si alguna de las bicicletas tiene el mismo Id que se busca. En caso de encontrarla retorna esa instancia de bicicleta, sino se encuentra retorna null

Al momento de implementar el método siempre me retorna null, no alcanzo divisar donde se encuentra el error, el método si lee el parámetro que se pasa y lo busca en el loop for pero no hace el return de esa instancia, siempre retorna null

```
public Bicicleta ConsultarBicicleta(String Id){
    Bicicleta consultaBicicleta = null;
    for(Bicicleta bicicleta : this.Bicicletas){
        if(bicicleta.getId().equals(Id)){
            consultaBicicleta = new Bicicleta(Id, bicicleta.getEnServicio());
            System.out.println(consultaBicicleta.getId()+", "+consultaBicicleta.getEnServicio());
        }
        else{
            consultaBicicleta = null;
        }
    }
    return consultaBicicleta;
}
```

Comment: En el if debes poner `return consultaBicicleta;`, de lo contrario el bucle agotará todos los elementos quedándose con el resultado del último. Puede que ni siquiera necesites crear una nueva instancia del objeto, ¿acaso el objeto que lees en el bucle no tiene ya las propiedades que se requieren?

Comment: por favor, hace el [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio...

Answer (score 4):

Debes poner un `return` dentro del `if`, de lo contrario, el código seguirá iterando sobre todos los elementos, quedándose con el último elemento, sea cual sea.

Por otra parte, no necesitas el `else`. Si analizas bien, `consultaBicicleta` es creado como un objeto `null`  y sólo cambiará si se cumple la condición.

Así debería funcionar:

```
public Bicicleta ConsultarBicicleta(String Id){
    Bicicleta consultaBicicleta = null;
    for(Bicicleta bicicleta : this.Bicicletas){
        if(bicicleta.getId().equals(Id)){
            consultaBicicleta = new Bicicleta(Id, bicicleta.getEnServicio());
            System.out.println(consultaBicicleta.getId()+", "+consultaBicicleta.getEnServicio());
            /*Aquí el bucle se detiene*/
            return consultaBicicleta;
        }
    }
    return consultaBicicleta;
}
```

### Nota de optimización del código

Es muy probable que sea redundante crear una instancia de `Bicicleta`, porque los elementos sobre los que estás iterando son ya instancias de dicha clase, por tanto, podrías retornar el mismo objeto que cumple la condición.

Esto debería bastar:

```
public Bicicleta ConsultarBicicleta(String Id){
    for(Bicicleta bicicleta : this.Bicicletas){
        if(bicicleta.getId().equals(Id)){
            System.out.println(bicicleta.getId()+", "+bicicleta.getEnServicio());
            /*Aquí el bucle se detiene*/
            return bicicleta;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Luego de hacer la prueba del codigo eliminando el else funciono a la perfeccion, gracias por el aporte

Comment: @WillDiaz aunque se agradece que digas gracias, la forma de decir gracias aqui es votando las publicaciones que te sirvieron, y aceptando aquellas que resolvieron el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción que puedes tomar es con las expresiones lambda.

Recuerda que las clases que extienden de [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) tienen los métodos de stream [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) y [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()); además podemos limitar que se detenga la búsqueda con [limit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long)).

- *filter*: nos sirve para filtrar los elementos que coincidan con el criterio de búsqueda.
- *findFirst*: nos devolverá un objeto `Optional<...>`. Esta clase [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) es especialmente útil en estos casos para saber la existencia del objeto o su inexistencia.
- *limit*: nos ayuda a truncar nuestro Stream para evitar que se siga buscando después de los **n** resultados encontrados.

## Código

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Bicycle> bikes = new ArrayList<>(3);
        bikes.add(new Bicycle("A7ERF54", "My brand"));
        bikes.add(new Bicycle("A7ER654", "My brand"));
        bikes.add(new Bicycle("A7ERL54", "My brand"));

         Optional<Bicycle> query = bikes.stream()
                .filter(el -> el.getId().equals("A7ERL54"))
                .limit(1)
                .findFirst();

        if (query.isPresent())
            System.out.println(query.get().toString());
        else
            System.out.println("Non existence");
    }

    private static class Bicycle {
        private final String id;
        private final String brand;

        public Bicycle(String id, String brand) {
            this.id = id;
            this.brand = brand;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bicycle\t\tID: " + id + "\t\tBrand: " + brand;
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Bicycle     ID: A7ERL54     Brand: My brand
```

**Anotaciones**

Como se puede observar, todo el código se puede reducir a una línea de código `Optional<Bicycle> query = bikes.stream().filter(el -> el.getId().equals("A7ERL54")).limit(1).findFirst();`.

Se usa el método [isEmpty](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isEmpty()) de la clase Optional para saber si encontró o no coincidencias con la búsqueda. Aunque tal vez te gustaría ver la función [ifPresentOrElse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse(java.util.function.Consumer,java.lang.Runnable))

Con esta última función podemos ahorrar incluso más líneas de código

La consulta e impresión quedaría simplemente así:

```java
Optional<Bicycle> query = bikes.stream()
        .filter(el -> el.getId().equals("A7ERL54"))
        .limit(1)
        .findFirst();
query.ifPresentOrElse(
        System.out::println,
        () -> System.out.println("Non existence")
);
```